# Introduction to Python, causing function to print true

Tags: python, function, return

This is one of my first times using Python, and I have a problem to solve, below is a method that prints true when something is entered inside of it. I don' t understand whats going on here so could someone try to explain what's going on here, and what would cause something to print this as true. Is there a specific kind of name for this kind of method? Some kind of strategy going on here?

Basically I'm looking for

- What would cause this to print true?
- Why does it print true with the keyword?

Thanks in advance, remember I'm a beginner with Python, so please try and not hate.

```
quam, quum="",""
class char:
    def __init__(self, *x): pass
    def __add__(self, x):
        try:
                  globals()['quum'] += x
        except:
                  return True
for i in [102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 122, 108, 105, 98, 32, 105, 109, 112, 111, 114, 116, 32, 100, 101, 99, 111, 109, 112, 114, 101, 115, 115, 32, 97, 115, 32, 121, 10, 102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 98, 105, 110, 97, 115, 99, 105, 105, 32, 105, 109, 112, 111, 114, 116, 32, 117, 110, 104, 101, 120, 108, 105, 102, 121, 32, 97, 115, 32, 117]:
    quam = char() + chr(i)

if char() + 100: exec(quum)
else: exec(quam)
c = 204112890334875644936547550670918483174507745028227181355093277104005052842989650193062069077845326 42489437847494411971123810887
hi = eval(y(u(hex(c)[1+1:1-1-1])))
print hi(raw_input("Your input:"))
```

Comment: If you're trying to learn python, trying to figure out the meaning of obfuscated code is not a good idea. Get a book instead, you can find a lot here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntroductoryBooks. IMHO if this is a practice from some python course, I suggest you to find a better course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is obviously some obfuscated code. you can get behind it by starting printing everything you don't understand, e.g. start with `quum`, a string that is filled with code and evalueated with `exec()`:

```
>>> print quum
from zlib import decompress as y
from binascii import unhexlify as u
```

now you know what's `y` and `u`

```
>>> u
<built-in function unhexlify>
>>> y
<built-in function decompress>
```

now the number `c` is processed somehow

```
>>> hex(c)
'0x789ccb49cc4d4a4954a8b0aab0b5552fc9c82c8e07a2e2fcdcd4f8f2d4cca294f89cfcfcecccbcf4f882ca928cfc3c7500ab851247L'
>>> hex(c)[1+1:1-1-1]
'789ccb49cc4d4a4954a8b0aab0b5552fc9c82c8e07a2e2fcdcd4f8f2d4cca294f89cfcfcecccbcf4f882ca928cfc3c7500ab851247'
```

looks like hexadecimal representations of some bytes, doesn't it?

```
>>> u(hex(c)[1+1:1-1-1])
'x\x9c\xcbI\xccMJIT\xa8\xb0\xaa\xb0\xb5U/\xc9\xc8,\x8e\x07\xa2\xe2\xfc\xdc\xd4\xf8\xf2\xd4\xcc\xa2\x94\xf8\x9c\xfc\xfc\xec\xcc\xbc\xf4\xf8\x82\xca\x92\x8c\xfc<u\x00\xab\x85\x12G'
```

let's unzip 'em!

```
>>> y(u(hex(c)[1+1:1-1-1]))
"lambda x:x=='this_is_some_weird_looking_python'"
```

yay, it's a string!

```
>>> hi = eval(y(u(hex(c)[1+1:1-1-1])))
>>> hi
<function <lambda> at 0x1dde938>
```

now that's just a definition of a lambda function that does return true if you enter `this_is_some_weird_looking_python`

simple, huh?